# How do we restrict the length of a combo box control in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Basically I want that the Title field(Combo Box) should not allow me to enter more than 40 characters.

Can you provide any pointers?

Comment: You're referring to the `ComboBox` control in the Ajax Control Toolkit, right?

Comment: @Paperjam...Can you provide some way in which we can restrict the length to be entered?

Answer (score 0):

I looks like the control itself does not have that functionality, so you will probably have to write your own version.

You could create a custom control to extend the `ComboxBox` control. Check out [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/08/08/creating-an-asp-net-ajax-toolkit-extender-control.aspx).

Another idea is to use jQuery to prevent more than 40 characters from being added to the `input` control the ComboBox control generates:

```
$(function() {

    var comboxBoxControlInput = $("#<%=comboBoxControlId.ClientID%>$TextBox");
    $(comboxBoxControlInput).keyup(function() {
        limitLenth(this, 40);
    });

});

function limitLength(control, length) {
    var currentContent = $(control).val();
    var currentLength = currentContent.length;
    if(currentLength > length) {
        $(control).val(currentContent.substr(0, length));
        return false;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it's a bit hacky. You have to get the ClientID of the ComboBox control (`<%=comboBoxControlId.ClientID%>`) and then append `$TextBox` to the end in order for jQuery to select the correct control.

Edit:
Another way to select the correct input control is to do this:

```
$("#<%=comboBoxControlId.ClientId%>").find("input[type=text]");
```

This selects the first text input within the `div` the ComboBox control creates.